# Stand alone java application without eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having an application which uses the eclipse plugins. But I want it to be run without using eclipse. ie as a standalone application(say suppose in command prompt). is it possible? If yes how?

thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Eclipse is build on a modular code framework called OSGI. At the heart of Eclipse is an OSGI container called Equinox. So you 'could' use just Equinox to run your code without Eclipse, but that task would be not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 3):

SWT and JFace can be used outside the Eclipse RCP platform as described here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace#Using_JFace_outside_the_Eclipse_platform. If you are making use of Eclipse bundles other than just the SWT and JFace ones it's unlikely you will get them to work properly.